# Using UniqueEntity outside of Symfony stack

Tags: doctrine-orm, unique, silex, symfony-validator

I have an app built on top of Silex and I'm using Doctrine as my ORM.

I have a problem where I'm trying to get a clean error for when a user tries to reuse an email, I found the validator [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) but it seems to be designed for the full stack version of Symfony.

My question is, is this true? I'm going a limb and assuming it as I haven't found anyone who successfully used it outside of Symfony.

My second question is, if I'm not able to use UniqueEntity, whats my next best option? I'm using the Symfony Validator component and would like to use something that's plugged into that to keep it all in the same block of code.

Comment: I used it in silex, but installation is rather complicated. As I remember it is necessary to create 2 services: 1.  service that implements `ManagerRegistry` interface. It is analog of `doctrine` service in symfony. 2. service for unique validation (just instance of UniqueEntity validator).

Comment: While it is possible you might find it easier to just implement your own unique email identifier.  The Symfony Doctrine Bridge UniqueEntity is highly engineered to handle a gazillion edge cases.  All you really need is to wrap a simple query inside of a custom constraint.   The docs show you how.

Comment: I'll just make a custom validator constraint, sounds like the easier way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use UniqueEntity with Silex.**

Here's the service provider package with the Doctrine `ManagerRegistry` implementation - [saxulum/saxulum-doctrine-orm-manager-registry-provider](https://github.com/saxulum/saxulum-doctrine-orm-manager-registry-provider). Also you can find the instructions how to use it with the `UniqueEntity` validator in [README](https://github.com/saxulum/saxulum-doctrine-orm-manager-registry-provider#validator).

**But you may want to implement you own `UniqueEntity` validator.**

For example, if you want to validate DTO object (or any non-entity object), because it's not supported by Symfony's `UniqueEntity` validator (see [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22592) on GitHub).

Comment: I actually decided to just build my own custom contraint